# How I can enumerate all endpoints of an API?

Tags: web-application, rest, api, enumeration, api-gateway

Let's say I have an API api.example.com and I want to test all endpoints. I don't have access to documentation, how I can enumerate all the endpoints?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on-topic here. Could you elaborate on why you think it is?

Comment: I am testing the security of an api, what I have learned that in most apis,  some endpoints are not protected and you can have unauthorised access

Comment: I'm assuming you were assigned this, as a pen-test? Then we should assume that an attacker can find the API endpoints. You may have to teach the customer about the problems with security-by-obscurity.

Answer (score 2):

From the outside, there's no generic method. A site can have as many (possibly obfuscated) endpoints as they wish.
You could, however, get lucky if there is an automatically generated site-map; it might just include a list of endpoints.

From the inside, it's possible. It can be labor-intensive, depending on how the site works. If you have access to the web server configuration, you can walk through it to find the endpoints.
For an Apache webserver, start with `httpd.conf` .
For IIS, you'll have to open the GUI and find the sites hosted by that IIS server, then find the endpoints on them.